# Are Util.* functions on JavaCard side channel resistant?

Tags: javacard

I am wondering if the Util.* functions in a JavaCard are normally side channel resistant.
Do there exist some JavaCards, which have side channel resistant Util.* functions?
I looked in several public JavaCard Security Targets. But neither one has security claims for the Util.* functions listed.

To achieve side channel resistance in Java itself without the help of native code seems to be hard, if not impossible. Therefore, a JavaCard should have side channel resistant Util.* functions, right?

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think I've seen anything like that. But there seems to be little need:

- `arrayCopy(byte[] src, short srcOff, byte[] dest, short destOff, short length)`
- `arrayCopyNonAtomic(byte[] src, short srcOff, byte[] dest, short destOff, short length)`
- `arrayFill(byte[] bArray, short bOff, short bLen, byte bValue)`
- `arrayFillNonAtomic(byte[] bArray, short bOff, short bLen, byte bValue)`

Copy and fill operations generally are not doing anything with the bits inside the arrays. They copy or replace the bytes, but they do that *irrespective of the content* of the bytes. Only at EEPROM or flash level could leakage occur - and that is unlikely to be resolved on the Java Card level.

**Warning**: spurious copying of data should still be avoided, writing to persistent memory especially may leak information.

---

- `getShort(byte[] bArray, short bOff)`
- `makeShort(byte b1, byte b2)`
- `setShort(byte[] bArray, short bOff, short sValue)`

Now these functions basically do not regard the contents of the bytes either. They just copy or shift the values of the memory in the right position, again *irrespective of the contents*.

For both the copy and short handling functions you could theoretically make a function that is not safe against side channel attacks, but in general you should be safe: making them insecure would actually be harder than making them secure.

---

- `arrayCompare(byte[] src, short srcOff, byte[] dest, short destOff, short length)`

Now this one would require specific programming to avoid side channel attacks.

Currently there seems no side channel-secure version of `arrayCompare`. This is kind of annoying as in 3.0.5 it *can* provide functionality to secure the result of the array compare using [`SensitiveResult`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacardx/security/SensitiveResult.html).

This is something that *should* be amended in the specification, but for now you may be stuck with programming it yourself.

Of course particular vendors may secure this call; it would make sense. However, relying on a particular vendor feature makes your applet less portable across implementations.

---

***Check your platform documentation if and how data access is vulnerable to attacks and platform specific mitigations.***

Comment: I think you only had timing attacks in mind. What about power leakage? Here, copying can leak the hamming distance.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I am not a native speaker and therefore I do not quite understand the sentence "... you would not be able to rectify at any but the most basic levels". What do you mean by "most basic levels"?

Comment: No that wasn't that clear: I meant you would need either hardware or HAL level support to make sure that information isn't leaked at that level.

Comment: I don't understand how you relate the _SensitiveResult_ class with side channel attacks. I think that _SensitiveResult_ is only related to LFI attacks.